# Cellular homology computation

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

I know the theory behind cellular homology, but I'm having troubles in the actual computation.
The cellular boundary formula states that:
$$d(e^n_{\alpha})=\sum_{\beta}d_{\alpha \beta}e^{n-1}_{\beta}$$
Where, if $n>1$:
$$d_{\alpha\beta}=\deg(\varphi_{\alpha\beta})$$
$$\varphi_{\alpha\beta}: S_{\alpha}^{n-1}\xrightarrow{\text{attaching map}}X^{n-1}\xrightarrow{\pi}\frac{X^{n-1}}{X^{n-1}-e^{n-1}_{\beta}}\cong S_{\beta}^{n-1}$$
Where the last homeomorphism is defined by $\Phi_{\beta}:D^{n-1}_{\beta}\to X$ (the characteristic map of $e^{n-1}_{\beta}$). In fact we can restrict $\Phi_{\beta}$ in the codomain to $X^{n-1}$ and then $\Phi_{\beta}$ passes to the quotients(as a homeomorphism!):
$$\tilde\Phi_{\beta}:\frac{D^{n-1}_{\beta}}{S^{n-2}_{\beta}}\to\frac{X^{n-1}}{X^{n-1}-e^{n-1}_{\beta}} $$
So:
$$\tilde\Phi_{\beta}^{-1}:\frac{X^{n-1}}{X^{n-1}-e^{n-1}_{\beta}}\to\frac{D^{n-1}_{\beta}}{S^{n-2}_{\beta}}\cong S^{n-1}_{\beta} $$

Where the last homeomorphism is canonical.

This is crystal clear! But when I read online examples of (non-trivial) computation, I just can't understand what's going on.
For example, sometimes I see the attaching map represented as a "word", and I don't understand what this representation means.
I didn't manage to find online any non-trivial examples of computation that actually shows in detail how to calculate these degrees rigorously.
(Maybe I just lack some intuition about the degree)

Now I'll try to show how I would compute the homology the thorus.

I'll choose the standard CW-decomposition of the thorus, so I have one $0$-cell,two $1$-cells, one $2$-cell:

$$0\leftarrow \mathbb{Z}\xleftarrow{d_1} \mathbb{Z}^2 \xleftarrow{d_2} \mathbb{Z}\leftarrow 0$$

Since there is only one $0$-cell we have $d_1=0$.
Now we compute $d_2$.
Let $\color{red}{e^1_1}$,$\color{blue}{e^1_2}$ be the two $1$-cells

[image]

The coefficient $d_{11}$:
$$d_{11}=\deg\left(\varphi_{11}:S_{1}^{1}\xrightarrow{\text{attaching map}}X^{1}\xrightarrow{\pi}\frac{X^{1}}{X^{1}-e^{1}_{\beta}}\cong S_{1}^{1}\right)$$

Intuitively the attaching map attachs the $2$-disk along the $1$-cells(intuitively we can divide the circumference in $4$ quarters; two opposite quarters are sent in the same $1$-cell and the four junction points of the quarters are sent in the only $0$-cell ).
Now since the canonical projection collapse the blue $1$-cell and the $0$-cell in one point, the map $\varphi_{11}:S^1_1\to S^1_1$ is:

[image]

Now:

$$\deg(\varphi_{11})=H_1(\varphi_{11})[\mathcal{C}]=[\varphi_{11}\circ \mathcal{C}]$$

Where $\mathcal{C}(x_0,x_1)=e^{2\pi ix_0}$ is the canonical generator of $H_1(S^1)$. Now I don't know how to proceed. According to the results $\deg(\varphi_{11})$ should be $0$, so $\varphi_{11}\circ \mathcal{C}$ should be a boundary. But I don't know if this is the right way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3480271/497007). Not to just plug my own old answer, but I think that it gives a bit of explanation about what it means to give an attaching map in terms of a "word" and how to use it to quickly determine the degree of the maps used in constructing the cellular chain complex. In this case, your word is $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ if we call your two $1$-cells $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @kamills Thank you, but I don't find it very helpful.

Comment: The generator of $H_1(S^1)$ is C which, in you last figure, is a loop that goes around the left circle once (Notice that the red and blue drawings come with a gluing direction. Once you add the appropriate arrows in, notice that going around the circle once means going first *along* the direction of red, *along* blue, *against* red, then *against* blue - which is encoded in the expression $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$) . Once you pass the loop through $\phi_{11}$, you're quotienting out the blue, so you're left with the image of the loop going *along* red then *against* red, i.e. $aa^{-1} = e$. So it is 0.

Comment: @User20354 That's really useful, but is there a way to make this rigorous? Why should  the degree correspond to number of times the map $\varphi_{11}$ wraps around the circle?

Comment: Exactly. So deg($\phi_{11}$) is a number d where $\phi_{11}:H_1 = \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow H_1 = \mathbb{Z}$ is $1 \mapsto d$ ( Of coruse taking $H_1 := H_1(S^1)$). Here, $\phi_{11}(1) = \phi_{11}(C) = 0$ since $\phi_{11}(C) = e_1e_1^{-1}$ (in your cellular notation) which is $0$. So $\phi_{11}$ maps $1 \mapsto 0=d$. (Using that under the isomorphism $H_1 \cong 
\mathbb{Z}, C \mapsto 1, 1 \mapsto C$.)

Comment: My problem is how do you justify formally that the degree of $\varphi_{11}$ is $0$. I understand intuitively that $\varphi_{11}$ wraps first counterclockwise and then clockwise around the circle, so the total number of "wrappings" is $0$. But I don't understand how this has anything to do with the degree(I don't know why the rigorous definition of degree is connected with this intuitive argument).

Comment: The map $S^1 \to S^1$ that sends $z \mapsto z^n$ induces a map on $H_1$ that sends $C$ to $nC$. There are a few ways to see this. One is to note that it induces multiplication by $n$ on $\pi_1(S^1)$, and then appeal to naturality of the Hurewicz isomorphism $\pi_1(S^1) \to H_1(S^1)$ to conclude the same on $H_1$. Another is to appeal to a local degree theorem (e.g., Hatcher 2.30/2). If you are just concerned about it in this problem, note that @User20354's comment above implies that $\phi_{11}$ is nullhomotopic, and constant maps always induce the $0$ map on homology.

Comment: Okay, but why does the comment imply that $\varphi_{11}$ is nullhomotic? Can you provide an explicit homotopy with a constant map?